# importing bootstrap-vue in Nuxt3 is not working (using nuxt.config.ts)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I followed the getting strated steps to create a nuxt3 based website:
https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/quick-start/

Well, except the part about installing visual studio code :-D.

After the site was working I tried adding Bootstrap-vue following the guide here:
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#nuxtjs-module

I manged to get the bootstrap stuff with npm which suprised me, but I cannot add it to the project via the nuxt.config.ts.
As far as I can tell, this file was called nuxt.config.js in past releases and differs from the new typescript based one.

To import bootstrap I have tried the following nuxt.config.ts file:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'
    ]
})
```

Sadly, when I try to add a bootstrap button (b-button) an error will show, that the component is unknown.
Makes me wish for a php based approach where an import is all that is needed :-|.

Does anyone have any idea where the problem is?

Comment: This module is maybe not yet [supported with Nuxt3](https://modules.nuxtjs.org/?q=bootstrap). Especially regarding [this issue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/6872). I think that I solution [like this](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins) is probably the way to go. Not sure of the exact configuration required tho. The JS/TS configuration doesn't have any specific impact so far.

Comment: you can try the new alpha release of bootstrap-vue 3 https://cdmoro.github.io/bootstrap-vue-3/getting-started/

Comment: @tzknc quite strange URL you got here.

Comment: @marianocodes my first comment is up to date regarding the issue, hence the possible choices at your disposition.

Comment: I don't fully get it. The link takes me to vue plugin documentation in the nuxt website. How are you planning to use it to implement bootstrap?