# Is there any way to use bootstrapVue 2 components in nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to migrate from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3 and the project has bootstrapVue dependency.

we know that there is no bootstrapVue version 3 available yet.

so i tried [this link](https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3) but
it is simply not working!

then i check [bootstrapVueNext](https://bootstrap-vue-next.github.io/bootstrap-vue-next/). it works great but some components are missing there(maybe 10%).

Is there somebody tried  [this link](https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3) before? i can really use an example.

any suggestion can be helpful.

Comment: VueBootstrap does not work with Vue3/Nuxt 3. I used Bootstrap 5 with Vue3 / Nuxt 3. You can write your own components. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671883/importing-bootstrap-vue-in-nuxt3-is-not-working-using-nuxt-config-ts